# How to get item count of a CharacterSet in Swift

Tags: swift, count, set

When I use the following Swift code in Xcode's 9.4 playground:

```
let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "woord")
print("charSet=\(charSet)")
```

I can see that charSet contains 4 unique items from the Xcode-playground output:

```
charSet=<CFCharacterSet Items(U+0064 U+006F U+0072 U+0077)>
```

Does anybody know how I can use something like charSet.count to give me the answer?

Comment: Your question should be about the task you are trying to solve which appears to be getting the unique character count of a string.

Comment: Agreed, but in general I was wondering how to get an item-count of all unique items in a given CharacterSet, e.g. something like CharacterSet.symbols.count or CharacterSet.controlCharacters.count.

Comment: Your question is what's known as an XY problem. You ask about a specific solution to a problem without stating the problem, and so those answering your question have to guess in order to help you. Better to say "I want to count the number of unique characters in a string. I'm trying to do that using a `CharacterSet`, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Yes Duncan, you are also right, I'll keep that in mind for other questions I might ask here! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that your goal is to get the count of unique characters in a string. `CharacterSet` is not the right choice for this.

You can create a `Set` from the string and get its count:

```
let chars = Set("woord")
print(chars.count)
```

Comment: Great rmaddy, thanks for the quick reply! I was searching in the wrong direction.